# Why xcode 4.2 location simulation does not allow to enter float values for latitude and longitude?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator, core-location

After successful installation of Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard, I tried to play with simulator - to play with location simulation. Tried entering custom location values with some float values for latitude (54.913743) and longitude (23.939154), but the values were truncated when I reopened custom location dialog box.

I was unable to get locationManager:didEnterRegion: called back when simulated using float values. Only worked using decimal (54, 23) values. Does this mean that location simulation works only when simulating location using decimal values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What locale are you using?..
It works perfectly for me when I use "48,2081743" and "16,3738189" because commas are the standard decimal separators in german..

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I just copied the values of lat. & long. from the code that were with a dot. Everything works perfectly when entering with commas.